# Where does this belong to 'flaws in my mantra'?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask a question to detect flaws in a mantra.

But I am not entirely sure wether this(mainsite) is the place to ask it.

To be conrete, the mantra would be: 'Consume only things that you can craft yourself and did so at least once'

Comment: The "mantra" language you're using makes me wonder if this isn't a *spiritual* question -- and *might* be appropriate on, say, [Buddhism.SE](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/)?